# husky install - .git can't be found - issue in local mac machine

Tags: react-native, husky, git-husky

I am facing this issue only for 1 project other similar react-native-based applications not facing any issue. I have also tried removing the husky references from my project, still getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: I have solved the issue. The steps mentioned below,

1) delete .git folder from your home directory in my case it is users/sandeeprajbhar/.git
then 2)  run : npx husky-init && yarn

Comment: You saved me a lot of time.